# How to configure IIS to allow an https page being iframed within an http page within the same domain?

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, iframe, http-headers

I have a site hosted in IIS 6.0 (I've also tested it with IIS 7.0, same result) and I've configured my page so that it only accepts iframes hosted in the same origin domain using this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2694329

I have added the "X-Frame-Options" field name and "SAMEORIGIN" value in the HTTP Headers tab in IIS.

That means "The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself."

Now my pages can't be hosted in any other website/domain which is fine and expected.

The problem is that I have an https page whose parent is an http page both of which within the same domain. I expected this to work but I get the bellow error:

```
This content cannot be displayed in a frame 

   To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.

   What you can try: 
    Open this content in a new window
```

How to configure my site or what HTTP Header to add to allow an https page being iframed within an http page?

I also tried using "ALLOW-FROM" header name and adding specifically my domain names:

```
"http://mydomain.com" and "https://mydomain.com"
```

but it said

```
"The custom header already exists in the list".
```

So does "Origin" refer to both the domain and protocol? if so that seems to be a design issue? Or is there any workaround?

Thanks,